# On click event not firing - Works in one instance, but not another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a `.click()` event binder on `.button-add`. In my original markup for one page, this works fine, however in the second, it doesn't and I'm absolutely stumped as to why.

Example one (working - an extraction from example 2): http://jsfiddle.net/EC3wA/

Example two (not working - full code): http://jsfiddle.net/rLKY4/

Both have exactly the same jQuery function for `$('.button-add').click(..`, but I just can't figure out what the second wouldn't work.

Any help if figuring out what the issue is would be greatly appreciated!

(Note: one thing I've tried to no avail is commenting `$('select[name=id]').change(..)`).

Comment: Yeah, well I can remove the portion that uses PHP entirely, since the results it's meant to fetch are already in the HTML, one sec. - http://jsfiddle.net/rLKY4/1/. Still doesn't run, so I'm thinking it's an issue in the HTML, but I just can't figure out what :/.

Answer (score -1):

Run the console and you will see a js error "unexpected token ; ".

```
 line 31:  var options = '<?php echo str_replace(array("\n","\r"), '', $geo_options); ?>';
```

You need to escape the single quotes.  The javascript is broken, that's why the button event handler is not bound.

Comment: Oh i c.. then you're getting that console error because jsfiddle cannot evaluate php.